# Translating the fields in an admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I can't seem to figure out how to use this thing:

I have these 3 models:
Recipe has an ingredient_list that is comprised of the IngredientType through the Ingredient model.
Here they are (simplified)

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     ingredient_list = models.ManyToManyField(IngredientType, through='Ingredient')
     difficulty =models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=DISH_DIFICULTY,
     default=INTERMEDIATE)
     cuisine = models.ManyToManyField(Cuisine, related_name='+', null=True,
     blank = True)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
     ingredient_type = models.ForeignKey(IngredientType)
     class Meta:
         app_label = 'vcb'
         verbose_name = _('Ingredient')
         verbose_name_plural = _('Ingredients')

     def __unicode__(self):
         return ''

class IngredientType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     plural_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     class Meta:
          app_label = 'vcb'
          verbose_name = _('Ingredient Type')
          verbose_name_plural = _('Ingredient Types')

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

Now in my recipe admin I have:

```
 class IngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ingredient
    extra = 0  

 class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [IngredientInline]
```

My problem is that all the fields, including the Ingredient tab in my admin form are not being translated.
I've specified translations, in the LC_MESSAGES->django.po, to all IngredientTypes objects and all other fields, but when opening the admin api or ingredient list, they're all in English.
(I've compiled the translations and synced them).

I've tried the django-modeltranslation approach, only to find that it can't work with a manyTomany Field.
Is there a form.py I should add? I've been using django default by now, but if that's a lead, do tell.

Help is much appreciated,
Nitzan

Comment: Are you using manage.py? Try syncing the database again by deleting and refilling it (if you're using sqlite). The question is also a bit complicated, so if you can provide a bit more detail it will help.

Comment: Did you make sure to run `python manage.py compilemessages`? When running in a Django shell, does `_('Ingredient')` translate properly? (Also, hey, long time :))

Comment: Hi Yuval! :) really long time! your a django programmer? that's good to know! Every thing is translated fine, the problem was I didn't have hooks for those word, so the makemessages didn't pick them up.